# dart JSON String convert to List String

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an API that calls the json String array as follows:

```
[
  "006.01.01",
  "006.01.01 1090",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B 521211",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B 521211",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
  "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111"
]
```

I intend to convert the json to the  List in the dart. I tried the script below :

```
json.decode(response.body).cast<List<String>();
```

but it didn't work, how should the script be correct?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The result of parsing a JSON list is a `List<dynamic>`. The return type of `jsonDecode` is just `dynamic`.

You can cast such a list to a `List<String>` as

```
List<String> stringList = (jsonDecode(input) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
```

You can also just use it as a `List<dynamic>` and then assign each value to `String`:

```
List<dynamic> rellyAStringList = jsonDecode(input);
for (String string in reallyAStringList) { ... }
```

The effect is approximately the same - each element is checked for being a string when it is taken out of the list.

Answer (score 15):

**Convert Json Data To List**

```
List<String> data = [
   "006.01.01",
   "006.01.01 1090",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B 521211",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B 521211",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
   "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111"
];

//your json string
String jsonString = json.encode(data);

//convert json string to list
List<String> newData = List<String>.from(json.decode(jsonString));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Hope it helps.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String jsonResponse = '''
    ["006.01.01",
    "006.01.01 1090",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 A 521219",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B 521211",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.950 052 B 521211",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111",
    "006.01.01 1090 1090.994 001 A 511111"]
  ''';

  dynamic jsonParsed = json.decode(jsonResponse);

//   print(jsonParsed);

  print(jsonParsed[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the outermost data is an object and you want to list it inside you can use the following:

```dart
    var json = '{"id":1,"tags":["a","b","c"]}';
    var data = jsonDecode(json);

    List<dynamic> rawTags = data['tags'];

    List<String> tags = rawTags.map(
      (item) {
        return item as String;
      },
    ).toList();

    print(tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to convert any dynamic Json to List of Strings maybe this approach:

```
List<String> _data = []; // List to store the result
const int MAXL = 40; // max length lines
String line = ''; // A single line
int i = 0; // To identify level recursion

void makeArrayList (Map ret) {

  // function to call at any level of recursion
  void CheckKeyValue (Map data) {
    i++;

    data.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value is Map) {
        _data.add('** $key *$i*');
        CheckKeyValue (value);
        i--;
      } else {
        if (value is List) {
          for (var el in value) {
            if (el is Map) {
              CheckKeyValue (el);
              i--;
            } else {
              line = '$key: $value'.length > MAXL ?
                     line.substring(0, MAXL) : '$key: $value';

              _data.add(line);
            }
            _data.add(''); // \n line
          }
        } else {
          line = '$key: $value'.length > MAXL ?
                 line.substring(0, MAXL) : '$key: $value';

          _data.add(line);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  CheckKeyValue (ret);
}
```