# Q: type 'String' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic'

Tags: dart

I have a map like:

`Map<String, dynamic> myMap;
 // do something to add data to myMap`

I want to update a key:value in `myMap`, i tried:

`myMap.update(mykey, '0' as dynamic);`

But i recive an error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic)
>   => dynamic'

Comment: if you want to pass string then use Map<String, String> instead of dynamic.

Comment: I cannot do it, because data from json is dynamic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376518/dart-json-string-convert-to-list-string see here looks like same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Map.update`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Map/update.html) takes a *function* as its second argument.  It doesn't seem like you need to use `Map.update`; you can just do `myMap[myKey] = '0'`;.