# How to serialize api response contains list in flutter?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

This is the  response I am getting from server. All the properties are String and int expect data. It is a list of objects. When serializing the response it shows error. Please explain what is wrong with my code. I am from javascript background. Serialization in flutter is different from javascript.

```
class ResponseModel {
  String image;
  int row;
  int column;
  int position;
  List<Data> data;

  ResponseModel({this.image, this.row, this.column, this.position});

  factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return ResponseModel(
      image: parsedJson['image'],
      row: parsedJson['row'],
      column: parsedJson['column'],
      position: parsedJson['position'],
    );
  }
}

class Data {
  String imageUrl;

  Data({this.imageUrl});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Data(imageUrl: parsedJson["imageUrl"]);
  }
}
```

```
    [
        {
            "type": "image",
            "row": 1,
            "column": 3,
            "position":"1",
            "data": [
                {
                    "imageUrl": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/276/294/image/6dad06016c6ab319.jpg?q=90"
                },
                {
                    "imageUrl": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/276/294/image/9ad209b0fc3d03e4.jpg?q=90"
                },
                {
                    "imageUrl": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/276/294/image/405e10d01fae5aa5.jpg?q=90"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "row": 1,
            "column": 2,
            "position":"3",
            "data": [
                {
                    "imageUrl": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/414/630/image/f186565389063212.jpg?q=90"
                },
                {
                    "imageUrl": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/414/630/image/3eda035d946b0ebf.jpg?q=90"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "row": 1,
            "column": 1,
            "position":"2",
            "data": [
                {
                    "imageUrl": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/1187/636/image/4436d492e2563998.jpg?q=90"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

```
      Future<dynamic> getData() async {
        final response = await http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g4o04");

        final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);

        final finalResponse = ResponseModel.fromJson(parsedJson);

        print(finalResponse);

        setState(() {
          data = parsedJson;
        });
      }
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMu3g.png)

Comment: Could you please include error message into your question?

Comment: Hi @StasIvanov, I added an image describing error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dart JSON String convert to List String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376518/dart-json-string-convert-to-list-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) tool and select dart Language

Comment: Hi @Omar Mahmoud, the tool was helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its because the response is a JSON array. Which means `json.decode(response.body)` returns a `List<dynamic>` and hence the variable `parsedJson` is `List`.
You're trying to pass this `List` as a parameter to the `ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>)` method which accepts a `Map` as the parameter.
In simple words, you're trying to pass a `List` where a `Map` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    final response = await http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g4o04");

    final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
    List<ResponseModel> responseList = <ResponseModel>[];
    parsedJson.foreach((element) {
    responseList.add(ResponseModel.fromJson(element));
    }) 
    ///Response list will have your data 
    print(responseList);    
  }
```

Your code should be something like this