# Can't convert Map to List in Dart, facing "Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>" error

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this question has been asked, but I'll explain my problem and show you what I've tried.

So, I receive a response from an API, that looks exactly like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Macarrão",
        "descricao": "Macarrão Parafuso 100g",
        "preco": 10.23,
        "imagem": "https://www.-------.com.br/ccstore/v1/images/?source=/file/v3396941523676425853/products/141618_0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Nescau",
        "descricao": "Achocolatado Nescau",
        "preco": 5.23,
        "imagem": "https://www.-------.com.br/ccstore/v1/images/?source=/file/v3396941523676425853/products/141618_0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Toddynho",
        "descricao": "Bedida láctea - Toddynho",
        "preco": 2.48,
        "imagem": "https://www.-------.com.br/ccstore/v1/images/?source=/file/v3396941523676425853/products/141618_0.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nome": "Toddynho",
        "descricao": "Bedida láctea - Toddynho",
        "preco": 2.48,
        "imagem": "https://www.-----.com.br/ccstore/v1/images/?source=/file/v3396941523676425853/products/141618_0.jpg"
    }
]
```

Those are products that have 5 attributes, and I want to display them(the products) on screen.
Right now my code looks like this:

```
Future<void> loadProducts() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_url));
    if (response.body == null) return;
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    data.forEach((productId, productData) {
      _items.add(
        Product(
          id: productId,
          nome: productData['nome'],
          descricao: productData['descricao'],
          preco: productData['preco'],
          imagem: productData['imagem'],
        ),
      );
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Product is

```
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String nome;
  final String descricao;
  final double preco;
  final String imagem;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.nome,
    required this.descricao,
    required this.preco,
    required this.imagem,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void toggleFavorite() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and I have tried solutions like this:

```
List<String> respApi =
        (jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376518/dart-json-string-convert-to-list-string) ,  or this one

```
var usersDataFromJson = parsedJson['data'];
List<String> userData = List<String>.from(usersDataFromJson);
```

that would result in the error `The argument type 'void Function(String, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)'`.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get the error on the line `_items.add`. So based on te code in my previous answer it should be like this

```
_items.add( 
   Product(
      id: element['id'] ,
      nome: element['nome'],
      descricao: element['descricao'],
      preco: element['preco'],
      imagem: element['imagem'],
    )
)
```

and you don't need to use `forEach` anymore. Also for your `Product` class I advice you declare `id` of type `int` instead of `String` to avoid errors since in your json id is an int.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your json, you see it's a List of Map, but on this line:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

you are putting it inside a Map so it's logic to get an error. To resolve the error, do this:

```
List<Map> data  = jsonDecode(response.body);
// or 
// List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = jsonDecode(response.body) ;
```

But if it throws *TypeError*, do this instead:

```
List data = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

And you can access your data like this:

```
for(var element in data) {
   element.forEach((k,v) {
      //operations
   }) ;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for your response. It definitely handles the error and gets it much closer to working, but it still throws one last error. It throws: "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
Tried calling: []("nome")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)"

What could be the cause for that? thx in advance

Comment: Look at my 2nd answer to resolve that problem.

Comment: I am using the Syntax from your second answer, however, upon trying to access the json and show it on screen, I do it like: 
_items.add(
          Product(
            id: productId,
            nome: productData['nome'],
            descricao: productData['descricao'],
            preco: 5,
            imagem:
                'https://www.----------------------------g',
          ),

and get the error I described above. Do you have a hint of what could be happening?

Comment: Sorry I mean the answer I have just posted. It took some time to edit since I'm using a phone.